# Delete an object inside an array of objects by value

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

Having the following nested array of objects:

```
[
    {
        "items": [
            {
                "name": "See data",
                "href": "/data",
            },
            {
                "name": "Account",
                "href": "/account",
                "icon": {}
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "items": [
            {
                "name": "name",
                "href": "/name",
                "icon": {}
            },
            {
                "name": "My Rooms",
                "href": "/rooms",
                "icon": {}
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "items": [
            {
                "name": "user",
                "href": "/user",
                "icon": {}
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

How it's possible to remove an inside object by name?

For example to remove the object with name "Account"?

A solution that works is `delete myData[0].items[1];` but it's kind of hardcoded.

Also tried like:

```
myData[0].items = myData[0].items.filter(function (item) {
  return item.name !== 'Account';
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `splice` to change the original array in-place and `findIndex` to find the index of the item to remove.

```
for (const {items} of data) {
    const i = items.findIndex(({name}) => name === 'Account');
    if (i > -1) items.splice(i, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` and `filter`

```js
const myData= [
    {
        "items": [
            {
                "name": "See data",
                "href": "/data",
            },
            {
                "name": "Account",
                "href": "/account",
                "icon": {}
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "items": [
            {
                "name": "name",
                "href": "/name",
                "icon": {}
            },
            {
                "name": "My Rooms",
                "href": "/rooms",
                "icon": {}
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "items": [
            {
                "name": "user",
                "href": "/user",
                "icon": {}
            }
        ]
    }
];


const removeByName = (data, targetName) => {
  return data.map(obj => ({
    ...obj,
    items: obj.items.filter(item => item.name !== targetName),
  }));
}

const updatedData = removeByName(myData, 'Account');

console.log(updatedData);
```